# RESTful Server Design in Yii

Tags: php, rest, yii

Hi i have been trawling the net in search of as much info i could get my mits on about creating a restful server in the Yii framework.

All the examples i have found so far have dealt with writing a restful application that deals with one model (IE Topic Or Posts)

The crux of my question is this, How should i deal with writing a restful server that deals with alot of Model types, ie client, brand, project, task?

Each Model object will need CRUD operations to be implemented so for example
To create a new brand the system requires a Client Id as will the other CRUD operations.

Should each Model Object have its own RESTFUl server or should there be come kind of controller that routes the RESTFUL requests to the corresponding Rest controller for the model object?
Should there be one Server that dynamically decides what model to work with like a switch (not keen on this idea personally)

Any kind of advice of how to achieve this kind of rest architecture would be really great

I think its also worth noting that the server i am building will be working with sproutcore on the front end and will only be returning JSON so any kind of format detection will not be required.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure in what context you mean "server" but if I undersand the rest of the question, I would use controller(s) combined with the URL Manager to create a RESTful service.

Comment: Hi yeah i thinks thats the route im gonna take, i think when i orignially started planning the app i was over thinking the problem!! im taking this approcah,

I have an ApiController that extends CController then the controllers dealing with the request all extend the api controller

Answer (score 10):

I'm developing RESTful application in Yii. So far everything is ok.

- Models. I have 2 kind of models:

  1. Managed via REST interface (i.e. created/deleted and so on). I called them `resources` and put into separate directory, but technically they're models extending `CActiveRecord`.
  2. Internal models used by application but not exposed to the world. Also, abstract model classes from which other models or resources are extended.

  Resource instance can be constructed from XML representation sent by REST client and can be converted to XML representation. You could define a base class `AbstractResource` which will deal with this and override construction/conversion methods in child resources if necessary.
- There is one controller for one resource. Controllers usually have four CRUD actions and possibly List action. The latter is used for search operations. It's a good idea to use class-based actions instead of inline actions, so you can reuse your actions in different controllers. For example, all my controllers use `ListAction` for searching.
- I have base controller which sends everything as `application/xml`. Also it deals with HTTP status codes and [handles all errors](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.error#handling-errors-using-an-action).
- All XML input coming from clients is validated using [Relax NG schemes](http://relaxng.org/). You'll need json validator.
- TDD rocks! I've extensively tested nearly everything. It helps a lot when doing refactoring. Use TDD. Write unit-tests for all your models, resources and application components. Also, writing functional tests are easier, because you don't have HTML/CSS/etc. You just have to send HTTP request and check returned headers, code and content. I used php_curl extension and it works great. Since you will probably do PUT, DELETE and other exotic requests you have to manually compose each HTTP request. In my case, each request also needed to be signed (this involves calculating checksums, hashes and so on), so it's nearly impossible to test my application manually.

I also recommend this excellent book: [RESTful Web Services](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529260).

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer!!!
Was really informative, i think what i have so far is sort of along the lines you outlined!

i have one access point, ApiController which sets alot of stuff up and defines actionAdd actionDelete actionUpdate List and actionView,

Im routing all requests like api/create, pattern=>'api/<model>' and using $_GET model to dynamically instantiate the requested model in the ApiController.  Everything seems to be working ok atm but im noticing im kinda repeating stuff in the to get the related data back for each type, i have 8 types to work with so really need to refactor

Answer (score 2):

Run through this [tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/175/how-to-create-a-rest-api/).  Just duplicate the controller actions.  Edit the second set of actions to interact with a new model.  For example, the tutorial calls for the following actions to be created in the controller:

```
public function actionList()
{
}
public function actionView()
{
}
public function actionCreate()
{
}
public function actionUpdate()
{
}
public function actionDelete()
{
}
```

You would create alternate actions for your second model.  Something like:

```
public function actionListB()
{
}
public function actionViewB()
{
}
public function actionCreateB()
{
}
public function actionUpdateB()
{
}
public function actionDeleteB()
{
}
```

If you need more information or clarification please leave a comment.  Good luck.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer i was starting to think i wouldnt get one :D This process was along the lines of what i was thinking, however could you clarify for me why it wouldnt be better to simply build the Yii backend as normal IE, have all the controllers layed out as per normal and simply provide a unified way of accessing said controllers with Url routinig rather than having one giant Api controller with CRUD operations for every model that is going to be used ?

Comment: im just trying to get an insight into the best way to allow this application be to be scaleable etc also bearing in mind this app will only server as a backend for the sproutcore front end, it will not need to function as a normal web application in terms of rendering views etc, calls will simply be made to a predefined url that will perform a specific tasks and only return data in the format specified in the url - Thanks alot for your help by the way its greatly appreciated!

Comment: My fault.  You're right about the Api controller.  It doesn't make sense to have one giant one.  Chopping it up would definitely scale better.

Answer (score 2):

I am going through a similar exercise here with my project.

I am trying to decide the best way to make it all work in an elegant, scalable way.
At the moment that's what I have:

```
/controllers/apiController
/controllers/api/v1/resourceaController <extends apiController>
/controllers/api/v1/resourcebController <extends apiController>
/controllers/api/v1/resourcecController <extends apiController>
```

The solution I am building has the URL rules redirecting users straight to the appropriate CRUD function in apiController based on the method used:

```
// REST API routes
array('api/list', 'pattern' => 'api/v<version:\d+>/<resource:\w+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
array('api/create', 'pattern' => 'api/v<version:\d+>/<resource:\w+>', 'verb'=>'POST'),
array('api/view', 'pattern' => 'api/v<version:\d+>/<resource:\w+>/<resource_id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
array('api/update', 'pattern' => 'api/v<version:\d+>/<resource:\w+>/<resource_id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'PUT'),
array('api/delete', 'pattern' => 'api/v<version:\d+>/<resource:\w+>/<resource_id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'DELETE'),
array('api/list', 'pattern' => 'api/v<version:\d+>/<resource:\w+>/<resource_id:\d+>/<association:\w+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
array('api/create', 'pattern' => 'api/v<version:\d+>/<resource:\w+>/<resource_id:\d+>/<association:\w+>', 'verb'=>'POST'),
array('api/view', 'pattern' => 'api/v<version:\d+>/<resource:\w+>/<resource_id:\d+>/<association:\w+>/<association_id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
array('api/update', 'pattern' => 'api/v<version:\d+>/<resource:\w+>/<resource_id:\d+>/<association:\w+>/<association_id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'PUT'),
array('api/delete', 'pattern' => 'api/v<version:\d+>/<resource:\w+>/<resource_id:\d+>/<association:\w+>/<association_id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'DELETE'),
```

The function that receives the call will try to instantiate the resource controller based on $_GET['resource'] and call the function stored in $_GET['association'].

I think this makes it scale fairly well, as we can have new versions of the API coming out, and all we have to do it to create something like /api/v2, /api/v2 and put all the required resource controllers in there.